# Seeking Orthomosaic Software

Tags: open-source, python, gis, orthophotography

I want to create an orthomosaic web app and i will be needing recommendations. I know of OpenDrone map and I can use that a guide. I will like to know of other suggestions and the language for development is going to be in python.

Comment: Are you looking for software libraries?  Thanks!